# Object oriented design for search history and filters

Tags: java, objective-c, oop, design-patterns

In my Android and iOS app (no matter, Java or Objective-C project) I have a search form and when user clicks a button to find something, object of class `FilterState` is created and that filter is used to produce a `URL` for server API, that returns a `JSON` with objects that match this filter.

I was asked to create a history of user searches recently. I created a new class `SearchHistoryItem` and it had almost the same fields like a FilterState class, but also could be saved in a database and retrieved. I created a separate class for saving filters history, because I thought that a history item is something different in real world than a filter item.

But now, I began to have doubts about this OO-design. I want to ask, weather I should not make any changes and continue to support two classes with almost the same fields or should I make refactoring and remove `SearchHistoryItem` class by transferring methods related to saving in database of different Filter states to the FilterState class ?

Comment: Code duplication is almost always a bad idea, you should consider either composition (where both classes contain a third that contains the shared functionality) or extention where classes extend one which holds the shared functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your main concern is over whether there is a way to share fields in an OO-design way. You are right, that code duplication of any type is usually problematic to maintain.

Consider this question: will these two objects diverge in their fields in the future? If the answer is "probably yes," you may be okay with duplicating fields in the short term. If the answer is "probably not," you should consider removing the duplication.

The two main options I see are:

- Inheritence (one class inherits from the other)
- Composition (both classes contain a third, which contains the shared fields)

Inheritence is usually okay if you want an `is-a` relationship. Is a `SearchHistoryItem` really a `FilterState`? It doesn't seem like it is. Composition would probably serve you better here.